# Show ajax jquery response inside table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to show data the response of the ajax call inside an html table. Right now it only shows the first data array and others are not shown.

I used append but it didnt work for me.Is there any other way to call all the other arrays.

**ajax function**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('/searchq/') }}",
    method: 'get',
    data: {
        clientemail: jQuery('#cemail').val(),
        clientname: jQuery('#cname').val(),
        productname: jQuery('#pname').val(),
        start: jQuery('#startdate').val(),
        end: jQuery('#enddate').val(),
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#content').html(
            "<td>" + result[0].id + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + result[0].name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + result[0].product_name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + result[0].created_at + "</td>"
        );
    }
});
```

**console**

[image]

I also tried this but then it shows nothing.

```
             success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#content").remove();

                        if (result== "err") {
                            alert("Something Happened Wrong! Please Try Again.");
                        } else {
                            var trHTML = '';
                            $.each(result.ReportArr, function (i, obj) {
                                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + obj.id + '</td><td>' + obj.name + '</td><td>' + obj.product_name + '</td><td>' +  obj.created_at + '</td></tr>';
                            });
                            $('#content').append(trHTML);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `$.each` be on `result`. From your console output, it certainly doesn't look like there's a `result.ReportArr` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers above use an unnecessary amount of DOM querying.  Try amending either of these solutions to use an in memory reference to your table, to prevent excessive DOM queries.

I assume you have a store of the table you're filling, using some statement such as:

```
     var myTableBody = $('#my-table-id tbody');
```

Moving from that, you should definitely use a loop to go over your result array.  I would argue that the jQuery $.each is overly verbose, and unnecessary in this case, since the return object should be a pure JS array.

```
    success: function (result) {
       result.forEach(function(resultRow){
          var tableRow = `<tr>
                            <td>
                              ${resultRow.id}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              ${resultRow.name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              ${resultRow.product_name}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              ${resultRow.created_at}
                            </td>
                           </tr>`;

           myTableBody
             .append(tableRow);
       });
    }
```

The most critical part of this solution, over the other two is the lack of persistant DOM Queries.  For a result set of 100 items, my solution still only queries the DOM for the table element 1 time.  Other solutions query the DOM for the table element for the number of items in the result list.

Per a suggestion from Phil in the comments, I'm adding a map implementation, as well.

```
    success: function (result) {
      let tableRows = result.map((resultRow) =>
           `<tr>
              <td>
                ${resultRow.id}
              </td>
              <td>
                ${resultRow.name}
              </td>
              <td>
                ${resultRow.product_name}
              </td>
              <td>
                ${resultRow.created_at}
              </td>
            </tr>`;
       );
       myTableBody.append(tableRows);
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer. You could also `map` the `result` array to an array of `<tr>...</tr>` strings and call `append()` only once with that array :)

Comment: @Phil, I updated the post with a Array.prototype.map implementation.  Let me know if you have additional edits!

Comment: @blackbird, if you prefer this solution, would you please update this to your accepted answer?

Comment: @RyanShohoney I don't think you want to use braces around the HTML string in `map`

Comment: @Phil, after a ton of reading, you're right.  In this context, the braces are inappropriate, and probably break the 'solution'.  I've updated it to account for that.  Thanks for your diligence!

Answer (score 3):

You can use $.each() method

```
...
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    $.each(result,function(index,item){ 
        $('#yourTable').append(
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + item.id + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + item.name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + item.product_name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + item.created_at + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" 
        );
    });
} 
...
```

`yourTable` could be id of your table.
in above example that table renders a new row for each index of your results.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use $.each method and then append it to the table's tbody if you have tbody.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('/searchq/') }}",
    method: 'get',
    data: {
        clientemail: jQuery('#cemail').val(),
        clientname: jQuery('#cname').val(),
        productname: jQuery('#pname').val(),
        start: jQuery('#startdate').val(),
        end: jQuery('#enddate').val(),
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        $.each(result, function(index, item) {
            var el = `
                <tr>
                  <td>${item.id}</td>
                  <td>${item.name}</td>
                  <td>${item.product_name}</td>
                  <td>${item.created_at}</td>
                </tr>
            `;

             $('#content > tbody').append(el);
        });
    }
});
```